# I have a button in my index.html ,open that html and want to perform on click action using the button and redirect it to different page

Tags: java

If the button inside index.html has id, then how to call onclick on that button inside java application using that id.
Here is the Java Code:

```
public class Abcd extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("fdg");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    webView = new WebView();
    webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    URL urlHello = getClass().getResource("/2/index.html");
    webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());
    root.getChildren().add(webView);
    scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();            
  }
}
```